# iPad - dont hide the keyboard for text field

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, hide

In my iPad application, first view is authentication view.
It has 4 square boxes as iphone password screen and user just have to enter the numbers on the keyboard. Here the square boxes are disabled.
Now iPad has keyboard hide button and its hiding the keyboard. The problem is that I'm not able to bring back the keyboard. How can I disable hiding the keyboard in this view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the authentication view a `UITextFieldDelegate` and add the following method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This will work only when there is no external keyboard connected.

Comment: @thebarcodeproject  Do you have a good way to hide the external keyboard from code?  :-)  His question was to keep the keyboard visible and not let it hide so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: When the external keyboard is connected, the keyboard will disappear from screen, but the text field will remain first responder. Its important for Satyam svv to remember that having the keyboard onscreen or not is not your only judge of whether the text view is the next responder.

You are right, and I am supporting your post, but there is a difference between "keeping the text view  as the First Responder" and whether there is a keyboard present onscreen. They are two separate states, that alter on the basis of what types of inputs are available, and should be treated differently.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.  Well, if there is a physical keyboard present it will still be directed to his text field this way which is what I think that he's after.  Good point though for some situations.

Comment: I think this is a BOOL instead of void:- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return NO;
}